# automatic playing of bag files

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone
my question is simple: I have two bag files to be played in sequence. Is there a way (for example, a launch file) to make this sequential execution automatic without need to perform it manually from the shell?
I want, in particular, first bag to be played. After end of playing, second bag must be executed. I can't use something like

```
rosbag play bag1.bag bag2.bag
```

since first bag has a timestamp whose year is 1970, so second bag cannot be played before 40 years are past...

thanks for support

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51898/automatic-playing-of-bag-files/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What about:

```
rosbag play bag1.bag
rosbag play bag2.bag
```

in a shell script.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1